# I am having trouble with using a downloaded library for python gui app building

Tags: linux, python

I am relatively new to linux and software development. I am trying to use tkinter and python to build a front end gui for a raspberry pi - arduino system. I have downloaded and extracted the files for active tcl and tkinter on the computer but I cannot get the libraries where they are needed to run the program and debug. I get this error.

```
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
/usr/local/lib/tcl8.6/tk8.6 /usr/local/lib/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /lib/tk8.6 /usr/library
```

I have run sudo ./install.sh and placed in the default folder and have a folder labeled tcl8.6 in the directory /usr/local/lib/ and in /usr/local/lib/lib/. I don't know what I am doing wrong and at this point my computer is so full of improperly downloaded libraries I've considered saving the few files I have and resetting the os. I am running elementary os 5.0 juno.

I believe I am not doing whatever this is:

```
After installation, make sure that the directory containing the installed executables (ActiveTcl/bin) is included in your PATH variable.
   export PATH="/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/bin:$PATH"
You can also add the man directory to your path to access the man page documentation on the command line.
   export PATH="/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/man:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get update` to update your list of package versions and sources and then `sudo apt-get install tk`, `sudo apt-get install tcl`, and `sudo apt-get install libtcl8.5`.